# Set CSS attribute based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a condition below which sets a CSS grid class based on the `usecase` length below:

```
jQuery(".uc"+useCases).addClass((landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 2) ?  'ibm-col-12-6' : 
 (landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 3) ? 'ibm-col-12-4' : 'ibm-col-12-3').attr('style','display:block');
```

Using the same method I want to add a width of % to a CSS class `.ibm-columns` based on the same above condition.

Below syntax is just a representation but I need the proper syntax

```
jQuery(".ibm-columns").css((landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 2) ? 'width: 60%;' : 
 (landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 3) ? 'width: 70%;' : 'width: 95%;');
```

Comment: Right, and what problem are you facing?

Comment: Given you are already adding the classes, why not use CSS to apply the style directly to those classes, rather than setting styles in JS?

Comment: @here any reason why the question is downvoted ? Would help posting the reason too

Comment: Look a the first two comments. Basically it is not clear what the problem is.

Comment: "Below syntax is just a representation but I need the proper syntax"- The line of code doesnt work. Hope its clear @Mitya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your syntax. `css()` accepts two arguments, the rule name and its value, yet you supply them both as a single string.

To fix this supply the values in an object:

```
jQuery(".ibm-columns").css((landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 2) ? 
   { 'width': '60%' } : 
   (landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 3) ? 
      { 'width': '70%' } : 
      { 'width': '95%' });
```

I would also suggest you break the ternary out to store the value in its own variable and supply that to `css()` to make the code more readable:

```
let width = landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 2 ? '60%' :
    landingPageData.description.useCases.length == 3 ? '70%' : '95%';

jQuery(".ibm-columns").css('width', width);
```